# Scrapy-Spash not crawling

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am attempting to do a very basic print out of links that are returned from searching for a company's annual reports at this link: https://www.mergentarchives.com/searchResults.php?searchType=annualReports&companyName=3Com+Corp.&compNumber=37958&aracompNumber=0

I need to use Splash to render the links as this website is written in javascript and search results are loaded dynamically. When I try to print out the list of links, the scraper just doesn't crawl. This is my very simple code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class MergentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mergent'
    start_urls = ['https://www.mergentarchives.com/searchResults.php?searchType=annualReports&companyName=3Com+Corp.&compNumber=37958&aracompNumber=0']


    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url + "/searchResults.php?searchType=annualReports&companyName=3Com+Corp.&compNumber=37958&aracompNumber=0"
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.start)
    
    def start(self,response):
        for document in response.css("a::attr(onclick"):
            print(document)
```

I have added these settings:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'mergent_scraper.middlewares.MergentScraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'mergent_scraper.middlewares.MergentScraperDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
SPLASH_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8050'
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

I am using docker using this command:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8050:8050 --rm scrapinghub/splash
```

What am I doing wrong? Why won't this spider crawl?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a logon for the website? If so you need to look at: [using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login). The scraper will not know there is a log on form.

A quick way to test would be to use the scrapy shell, send the splash request and see if you get the page you are expecting.